# sql like operator to get the numbers only

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers

This is I think a simple problem but not getting the solution yet. I would like to get the valid numbers only from a column as explained here.

Lets say we have a varchar column with following values

```
ABC
Italy
Apple
234.62
2:234:43:22
France
6435.23
2
Lions
```

Here the problem is to select numbers only

`select * from tbl where answer like '%[0-9]%'`  would have done it but it returns

```
    234.62
    2:234:43:22
    6435.23
    2
```

Here, obviously, 2:234:43:22 is not desired as it is not valid number.

The desired result is

```
        234.62
        6435.23
        2
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try this

[ISNUMERIC (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input
>   expression evaluates to a valid
>   numeric data type; otherwise it
>   returns 0.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Col VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'ABC' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Italy' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Apple' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '234.62' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2:234:43:22' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'France' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '6435.23'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Lions'

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
WHERE   ISNUMERIC(Col) = 1
```

Comment: +1 This is a far better solution than mine. I'll leave mine, since it appears to work on this limited case but just goes to show I need to learn all the inbuilt functions.

Comment: Sure David Same here (need to learn inbuilt functions) :) ! Your answer with like is also fine one

Comment: Yes. ISNUMERIC has problems. @gbn mentioned `+`, it accepts negatives, also try `ISNUMERIC('-1.0e+5')`. You'd have to say ISNUMERIC('+' + Col + 'e0'). Which makes the `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%` solution at least as good, if not better.

Answer (score 65):

You can use the following to only include valid characters:

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM @Table
WHERE Col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

**Results**

```
Col
---------
234.62
6435.23
2
```

Comment: [Needs a collate clause or use a set instead of a range](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34730/why-are-non-digits-like-0-9/34731#34731)

Comment: I know that this is a very dated post, but I just came across it. I still feel it necessary to point out that this will return an IP address (or any other value with multiple decimal points).

Comment: This is a great answer!  To address the above comments, just include isnumeric: `WHERE Col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND ISNUMERIC(Col) = 1`

Answer (score 14):

Try something like this - it works for the cases you have mentioned.

```
select * from tbl
where answer like '%[0-9]%'
and answer not like '%[:]%'
and answer not like '%[A-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

With SQL 2012 and later, you could use `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` to try converting to a numeric type, e.g. `TRY_CAST(answer AS float) IS NOT NULL` -- note though that this will match scientific notation too (1+E34).  (If you use `decimal`, then scientific notation won't match)

Answer (score 0):

what might get you where you want in plain SQL92:

```
select * from tbl where lower(answer) = upper(answer)
```

or, if you also want to be robust for leading/trailing spaces:

```
select * from tbl where lower(answer) = trim(upper(answer))
```

Comment: This will match strings like `2.3.4` or `2-5` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM @Table
WHERE Col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND ISNUMERIC(Col)=1 AND Col!='.'
```

Explanation:
`NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'` means "no string with a character that is not a figure or a dot"
`ISNUMERIC(Col)=1` means "the SQL function to identify a numeric must return OK" (that can avoid strings with multiple dots)
`Col!='.'` means "Col is not a dot" (a dot is considered as numeric by above function)

Next stop: the Regex gurus that will do this in a single line ;)

a+,=)
-=Clement=-