# TSQL String matching question

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pattern-matching

I am trying to match 2 strings using TSQL.

First string:      `ABCD DFHG KLJKL`

Second string: `ABCD DFHG KLJKL - 4536764`

Matching rule: if second string begins with the first string followed by " - " (that is, space, dash, space) and a set of numbers (and nothing else), consider it a match.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the first string is a substring anywhere? What if there are extraneous characters? Would `ABC` match `-123ABC1545555645` It seems to follow the stated rules.

Comment: SQL Server 2008. The first string should be a substring from the start of the second substring and not anywhere. So it is a match if and only if the second string has the first string from the start, and ends with a "-" and some number.

Comment: And must the `-` exactly follow the first string with no additional characters inbetween? Would `ABC` match `ABC£$-123`?

Comment: The - should follow the first string with just one space in front and back. So ABC would match ABC - 12345

Answer (score 4):

I have two answers for you.

1. Assuming that your FirstString values do not contain any of the characters `%`, `_`, OR `[`, this will return what you're asking for. Not only does it guarantee that the second string begins with the first and is followed by space-dash-space and a number, it also makes sure that only numbers follow from that point onward.

   If your table is very wide at all, then a nonclustered index that includes FirstString and SecondString as well as whatever other columns you want SELECTed (or they're in the clustered index) will make that index fully cover the query and could greatly improve performance.

   ```
   SELECT * 
      FROM Strings
      WHERE
         SecondString LIKE FirstString + ' - [0-9]%'
         AND SecondString NOT LIKE FirstString + ' - %[^0-9]%';
   ```

   I would also submit that if the FirstString is blank and SecondString starts immediately with ' - ' then it is correct per the specs.
2. If your FirstString value DOES contain any of the above characters, then here's one way to handle that:

   ```
   SELECT * 
      FROM Strings
      WHERE
         Left(SecondString, Len(FirstString) + 3) = FirstString + ' - '
         AND Len(SecondString) > Len(FirstString) + 3
         AND Substring(SecondString, Len(FirstString) + 4, 2147483647) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
   ```

   This is kind of strange territory, here, so I would experiment also with this version to see if it performs any better:

   ```
   WITH S AS (
      SELECT
         *,
         Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
            FirstString,
            '\', '\\'),
            '%', '\%'),
            '_', '\_'),
            '[', '\[' --' just a comment to fix wonky code colorization
         ) FirstStringEscaped
      FROM Strings
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM S
   WHERE
      SecondString LIKE FirstStringEscaped + ' - [0-9]%' ESCAPE '\' --'
      AND SecondString NOT LIKE FirstStringEscaped + ' - %[^0-9]%' ESCAPE '\'; --'
   ```

Please note that if you want to properly handle spaces at the end of FirstString, some adjustment may be required (the second query which uses `Len` does not handle this case properly).

Comment: I think you are assuming here that `FirstString` does not contain any characters of particular significance in patterns such as `%`. If    FirstString is `ABC%` and second string is `ABCQWE - 123` this returns a match.

Answer (score 1):

This query satisfies all the requirements.

```
select *
from #strings
where
  -- s2 contains s1 as the prefix.
  -- The addition of '.' is because sql considers ('abc' = 'abc ')
  LEFT(s2,Len(s1))+'.' = s1+'.'

  -- next 4 chars are space-dash-space-digit
  AND SUBSTRING(s2, Len(s1)+1, Len(s2)) LIKE ' - %[0-9]%'

  -- no non-digit letters after that
  AND NOT STUFF(s2, 1, len(s1)+4, '') LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 

  AND s1 > '' -- reject empty string1, added just in case
```

Here's a test table, showing you all the test cases

```
create table #strings (s1 varchar(100), s2 varchar(100))
insert into #strings values
    ('ABCD DFHG KLJKL', 'ABCD DFHG KLJKL - abc'), -- no, not number
    ('ABCD DFHG KLJKL', 'ABCD DFHG KLJKL - 123'), -- yes
    ('ABCD ', 'ABCD - 123'), -- no, 2nd string is first + '-' without space
    ('ABCD DFHG KLJKL - 123', 'ABCD DFHG KLJKL'), -- no, reversed
    ('KLJKL', 'KLJKL - 1.234'), -- ?? no, 2nd string is not digits only
    ('KL%', 'KLJKL - 1.234'), -- ?? no, 2nd string is not digits only
    ('', ' - 5234'), -- ?? no, blank string is not a match
    (null, ' - 1234'), -- ?? no, null is not equal to blank, which is not a match anyway
    ('ABCD DFHG KLJKL', null) -- no, of course not
```

Comment: I agree with more closely matching the requirements, but I think some things can be simplified.

Comment: Actually, like @Martin said in a comment on my answer, you're assuming here that FirstString does not contain any characters of particular significance in patterns such as %. If FirstString is `ABC%` and second string is `ABCQWE - 123` this returns a match. It seems your first answer might have been better, depending on whether the strings can contain these characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from theTable 
where SecondString like FirstString + ' - %[0-9]'
and SecondString not like FirstString + ' - %[^0-9]%'
```

This will select anything that has your string, followed by 1 space, followed by a dash, followed by 1 more space, followed by any set of numbers, and nothing but numbers.

EDITED: To filter out results with any cruft, not just letters, following the dash.

Comment: This best meets the criteria so far, considering we don't know anything else about "the number" at the end of the string.

Comment: Except it doesn't... matches when there is at least one number at the end, as well as a ton of other cruft, e.g. when FirstString = `abc` and SecondString = `abc - def alj2139087@[23 -=#@ ": ljskla 3wh5`

Comment: It's funny how all the answers are starting to look almost identical once the comments have hit. :) Not to say that your answer is bad by any means.

Comment: Gah! I didn't even see that cyberwiki's, yours, and mine are almost the same until after I posted the latest update.  I got the last line from this previous SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032742/sql-like-operator-to-get-the-numbers-only

Comment: I like your solution for the last condition... it completely removes any function and is best. But the first condition bothers me, putting the number at the end instead of right after the dash. I know it won't matter in this case, but in another query where FirstString comes from another table, your condition won't be sargable on SecondString.

Comment: Wouldn't the last condition prevent any potential use of indexes anyway?

Comment: No, because the other condition can be used to perform an index seek, or index range seek. If the row is not found in the index this means the second condition doesn't even have to be checked. Only after locating the data and making sure the first condition matches would the second condition be applied. `LIKE 'LeadingChars%'` is specially SARGable in a way other LIKE conditions are not.

Comment: Actually, like @Martin said in a comment on my answer, you're assuming here that FirstString does not contain any characters of particular significance in patterns such as %. If FirstString is `ABC%` and second string is `ABCQWE - 123` this returns a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from theTable 
where (FirstString = SecondString) 
or (FirstString = SUBSTRING(SecondString, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SecondString))
```

Comment: don't forget about the space if his data always include it following the `FirstString`