# Sql Server's regex LIKE - behaviour clarification?

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

Someone asked [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032742/sql-like-operator-to-get-the-numbers-only)  how to get only values which are a number :

So , if the table is :

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
      Col nVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'ABC' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '234.62' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '10:10:10:10' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'France' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2'
```

then - the desired results are :

```
234.62
2
```

But when I tested this query :

```
SELECT  * FROM    @Table WHERE Col   LIKE '%[0-9.]%' --expected to see only 234.62
```

it showed :

```
234.62
10:10:10:10
2
```

**Question #1**

How come `10:10:10:10 , 2` satisfies the condition ?

**Question #2**

I saw [*this answer here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032768/859154) which does work

```
SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE Col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

But I don't understand why this works. AFAIU - it selects all  values which are `not like (not(has number) and not( has dot))` which is ===>(de morgan)===> not like ( has number or has dot)

Can someone please shed  light ?

nb I already know that isnumeric can be used also , but it's unsafe (+). also valid wildcards are `%,_,[],[^]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any particular use of `[set]` within a `LIKE` expression is a check against *one* character in the target string.

So, `LIKE '%[0-9.]%'` says - `%` - match 0-to-many arbitrary characters, then `[0-9.]` match one character in the set `0-9.`, and then `%` match 0-to-many arbitrary characters. Paraphrased, it says "match any string that contains at least one character in the set `0-9.`". So, `10:10:10:10` can be matched as 0 arbitrary characters, then `1` matches `[0-9.]`, and then `0:10:10:10` matches the final `%`.

`LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'` says - `%` - match 0-to-many arbitrary characters, then `[^0-9.]` match one character *not* in the set `0-9.`, and then `%` match 0-to-many arbitrary characters. Paraphrased, it says "match any string that contains at least one character outside of the set `0-9.`. So when we apply the `NOT` to the front of that, we are saying "match any string that *doesn't* contain at least one character outside of the set `0-9.`" or "match strings that only contain characters *in* the set `0-9.`.

Essentially, the double-negative is a way to make an assertion about *all* characters in the string.

Comment: mmmm it also matches `.`