# How to retrieve only integer values from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How to retrieve only the integer value from this column?

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_data (
    [Name] nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO tbl_data VALUES
('Nikesh'),
('113'),
('sunam'),
('sudhir'),
('2.30'),
('ankit'),
('675')
```

Output I need:

```
Name
-----
113
675
```

Comment: This is a **horribly bad design** to begin with.... any column should only ever contain **one type of data** - either the columns is an `int` column, or a string - but don't mix both things in one single column

Comment: Stop right now and redesign your database.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. Do you know Ajit?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, it is not a duplicate.The other query is about NUMBERS not INTEGERS

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, what's wrong with the most upvoted answer on that duplicate target? `SELECT * FROM @Table
WHERE Col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` Just a small change to remove `.` and it **is** about integers.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, remove a `.` from a regular expression and it won't work any more :-). Also, I expect **all** right answers to fit the question not only the most upvoted one.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, well, it does work in my tests. It is better to list values instead of the range in the `LIKE` expression and specify collation explicitly, though, as explained in the [answer on dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34731/57105). I included that link in my answer here.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, I didn't talk about your answer (I upvoted it), but on the other answers on the NUMBERS question.

Answer (score 6):

Taking both most upvoted [answer on the duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032768/4116017) and removing a `.` from the code, plus a comment from that answer to [Why are non-digits LIKE [0-9]?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34731/57105), the accurate answer to this question about integers is this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM tbl_data
WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%[^0123456789]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: It is not working with scientific notations

Comment: @H.Fadlallah, you are right, but usually integers are not meant to be written in scientific notation.

Comment: You're right @Vladimir

Answer (score 5):

```
Select name from tbl_data where Isnumeric(name) = 1 and name not like '%.%'
```

Comment: This answer doesn't deal with float notation, e.g. 123e4

Comment: you can and name not like '%e%' to the where clause

Comment: @H.Fadlallah why you use %e% here we can only use %.% which will give us only integer values.

Comment: It is for the scientific notation 12e31 in float type

Answer (score 4):

You can use [XML.value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx):

```
;WITH tbl_data AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('Nikesh'),
('113'),
('sunam'),
('sudhir'),
('2.30'),
('ankit'),
('675')
) as t([Name])
)

SELECT *
FROM tbl_data
WHERE CAST([Name] as xml).value('. cast as xs:integer?','int') IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
Name
113
675
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the IsNumeric function.

For more information please go to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Msdn have an example:

```
USE master;  
GO  
SELECT name, isnumeric(name) AS IsNameANumber, database_id, isnumeric(database_id) AS IsIdANumber   
FROM sys.databases;  
GO
```

But bear in mind that your design does not look good. You should only store one data type per column.

Thanks

Comment: This answer is about all type of NUMBERS and not INTEGERS