# How to filter subform in datasheet view by textbox? #likeoperator #whereclause

Tags: ms-access, vba

I try to filter a subform in datasheet view depending on an optionframe by a textbox on the main form when pushing the search button. I tried 2 methods so far:

1) altering the select query the subform is based on using a like operator in the where clause 
 -> does not work (problem with where clause)

2) changing the filter on the subform filter event by using the like operator -> does not work (Error: "type mismatch"; commented out in the following code)

I'm thankful for any hint/advice!

here is my code of the search button on-click event:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim strSubQry, strFilter, SearchField As String
On Error GoTo Err_btnSearch_Click
SearchField = Me.txtSearchBox
If IsNull(Me.txtSearchBox) Or Me.txtSearchBox = "" Then
  MsgBox "Please enter keyword before searching!", vbOKOnly
  Me.txtSearchBox.SetFocus
Else
  Select Case Me.FrameSearchOptions
   Case Is = 1 'Order No Intern
    strSubQry = " SELECT tblShipment.ShipID, tblOrder.OrderNoIntern, tblOrder.CustomerName, tblOrder.CustomerPO, tblOrder.CustomerPN, tblShipment.ShipQTY, " & _
    " FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN tblShipment " & _
    " ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblShipment.OrderID_FK " & _
    " WHERE  ((tblOrder.[OrderNoIntern] Like " & SearchField & "*""));"

    ' strFilter = "[OrderNoIntern]" Like " & Chr(34) & SearchField & " * " & Chr(34)"

   Case Is = 2 'Customer Name
    strSubQry = " SELECT tblShipment.ShipID, tblOrder.OrderNoIntern, tblOrder.CustomerName, tblOrder.CustomerPO, tblOrder.CustomerPN, tblShipment.ShipQTY, " & _
    " FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN tblShipment " & _
    " ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblShipment.OrderID_FK " & _
    " WHERE  ((tblOrder.[CustomerName] Like " & SearchField & "*""));"

    ' strFilter = "[CustomerName]" Like "& Chr(34) & SearchField & " * " & Chr(34)"

   Case Is = 3 'Customer PO
    strSubQry = " SELECT tblShipment.ShipID, tblOrder.OrderNoIntern, tblOrder.CustomerName, tblOrder.CustomerPO, tblOrder.CustomerPN, tblShipment.ShipQTY, " & _
    " FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN tblShipment " & _
    " ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblShipment.OrderID_FK " & _
    " WHERE  ((tblOrder.[CustomerPO] Like " & SearchField & "*""));"

    ' strFilter = "[CustomerPO]" Like " & Chr(34) & SearchField & " * " & Chr(34)"

    Case Is = 4 'Customer P/N
     strSubQry = " SELECT tblShipment.ShipID, tblOrder.OrderNoIntern, tblOrder.CustomerName, tblOrder.CustomerPO, tblOrder.CustomerPN, tblShipment.ShipQTY, " & _
     " FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN tblShipment " & _
     " ON tblOrder.OrderID = tblShipment.OrderID_FK " & _
     " WHERE  ((tblOrder.[CustomerPN] Like " & SearchField & "*""));"

     ' strFilter = "[CustomerPN]" Like " & Chr(34) & SearchField & " * " & Chr(34)"

 End Select
End If
Me.sfrmShipmentsDS.Form.RecordSource = strSubQry
Me.sfrmShipmentsDS.Requery

'Me.sfrmShipmentsDS.Form.Filter = strFilter
'Me.sfrmShipmentsDS.Form.FilterOn = True
Exit_btnSearch_Click:
    Exit Sub
Err_btnSearch_Click:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Exit_btnSearch_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for string values but not escaping them correctly so this line

```
   " WHERE  ((tblOrder.[OrderNoIntern] Like " & SearchField & "*""));"
```

Should be

```
   " WHERE  tblOrder.[OrderNoIntern] Like '" & SearchField & "*';"
```

You can lose the brackets unless you are grouping multiple AND and OR where clauses which you aren't.
Your commented out lines are almost right but again not constructed quite correctly.

Comment: thank you very much! I knew I had a little mistake but didnt understand what and why. now I got it! 
do I need the grouped where clauses when I have more then one where condition?

Comment: tbh I don't bother with the brackets when building where clause at all, unless it would effect the way in which the where clauses are applied. It only comes into play when you mix multiple AND and OR criteria. Access is obsessed with adding millions of brackets when it creates SQL statements, _mostly_ unnecessarily.

Comment: okay... true, thats where I got them from. so I was quite confused ;-) Thank you very much again!

Comment: May I ask another question: do you think it is possible to optimize this kind of code performancewise or does it not affect the performance when changing recordsources?

Comment: I would ensure that all your search fields are indexed at a table level. Generally speaking a recordset that is restricted by a where clause is much more efficient than loading the entire recordset then applying a filter. You aren't doing it, but if at all possible avoid where clauses with a a wildcard at the beginning  `(Like *Sometext* )`. Initial wildcards searches don't use indexes and become very slow very quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much! my last question: How do I search for a numeric value using the LIKE operator? by skipping the single quotes?

Comment: You wouldn't normally, you would use > and < to get values between certain other values. After all 100 is not like 1000 but if you typed 100* you would get both values. If I missed your point this thread will clarify further https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032742/sql-like-operator-to-get-the-numbers-only

Comment: sorry, my questions was not clear enough. I meant how I search for a numeric textfield or variable. in my code here `SearchField` is a string because the table fields I search in are short text... but how do I code the where clause when I search in a numeric table field? I guess I have to set
`dim SearchField as Int` and have to change the like operator as well?!

Comment: If you Dim Searchfield as Variant it will become whatever type of variable is assigned to it. And yes assuming you are looking for specific values either = , >=, <=, <> etc as operators.